# ASP.NET MVC authentication cookie

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My web application authentication cookies times out after a day when I try to login again.
I'm trying to access the application through a Nokia browser and Internet Explorer and both have the same behavior.

This is my Logon process:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1054:UriParametersShouldNotBeStrings",
                      Justification = "Needs to take same parameter type as Controller.Redirect()")]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (MembershipService.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
        {
            //FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
            FormsAuthenticationTicket Authticket = new
                        FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
                        model.UserName,
                        DateTime.Now,
                        DateTime.Now.AddYears(1),
                        true,
                        "",
                        FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

            string hash = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(Authticket);

            HttpCookie Authcookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hash);

            if (Authticket.IsPersistent) Authcookie.Expires = Authticket.Expiration;

            Response.Cookies.Add(Authcookie);

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

My `web.config` settings:

```
<forms loginUrl="~/consignment/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" protection="All" name=".consignmentauthadmin"/>
```

I'm trying:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1054:UriParametersShouldNotBeStrings",
                     Justification = "Needs to take same parameter type as Controller.Redirect()")]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (MembershipService.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
        {
            //FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
            FormsAuthenticationTicket Authticket = new
                        FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
                        model.UserName,
                        DateTime.Now,
                        DateTime.Now.AddYears(1),
                        true,
                        "",
                        FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

            string hash = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(Authticket);

            HttpCookie Authcookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hash);

            if (Authticket.IsPersistent) Authcookie.Expires = Authticket.Expiration;

            Response.Cookies.Add(Authcookie);

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

I don't want the authentication to expire until I log off from the application.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I do not see anything problematic, maybe you need to open your cookie and read it by your browser to see what data you have put on and if the date is the correct. Then maybe your browser delete it, or not find it.

Comment: I have read the cookie and this is the info I got back 8 hrs ago. 
cookie details:
Expiration Date: 20/07/2011 12:00:00 a.m.
Expired: False

When I tried it again this morning the cookie had expired. The web application is running under a virtual directory so could it be that it might be picking up expiration from the root directory?

Comment: How read the cookie? in Server C#? or Client Javascript?

Answer (score 2):

Try looking at your webserver IIS application pool, it has an "application refresh" which is setup by default.
turn it off... that should fix your problem.

Comment: @ace did you get solution ?